# init.d service died

Tags: shell, daemon, ubuntu-11.04, init.d

Adapting some code from a linux forum, I've added a service script to /etc/init.d on my ubuntu natty server to start/stop/restart node.js
It literally was working the first day I made it, but then today, after viewing my website this morning, the server threw a 404, and upon further inspection, the node.js process was gone.
So I went to start the service again, only this time, node.js didn't start at all, and ever since I haven't been able to get my service script working.

Below is the entire script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Node Server Startup
#

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting node: "
        daemon node /usr/local/www/server.js
        echo
        touch /var/lock/subsys/node
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down node: "
        killall node
        echo
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/node
        rm -f /var/run/node.pid
        ;;
  status)
        status node
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading node: "
        killall node -HUP
        echo
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Anything in `/var/log/messages`? Do you get an error when you run `daemon node /usr/local/www/server.js` ?

Comment: nothing special in `/var/log/messages` and `daemon node /usr/local/www/server.js` just executes, but no node.js processes are even started.

Answer (score 0):

The script that you adapted is written for Red Hat-based. The trantional SysV init script on Debian-based using `start-stop-daemon` instead of `daemon` in `start()` function. Ubuntu 11.04 is using [Upstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto). Take a look at [this](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly question, but did you remove the /var/lock/subsys/node and /var/run/node.pid before trying to start the service?